# Infinite loop render with React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So a friend and I are making our first proyect and we are using React, and we don't know how React does many things and we are getting an infinite loop of re-renders. We are making a products page and it works fine the only problem is when we want to filter those products.
Whenever you click in one of those filters the page breaks beacause of infinite loops

**Products.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { CartState } from "../$-context/Context";


import {
  ButtonAllProducts,
  ButtonBakery,
  ButtonHotDrinks,
  ButtonsPagination,
} from "./Buttons";
import SingleProduct from "./SingleProduct";

const Products = () => {
  const renderManager = 0;
  
  let sortedProducts = [];

  const cardsPerPage = 12;

  const [allCategories, setAllCategories] = useState([]);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([].splice(0, 12));

  // const [cards, setProducts] = useState();

  const {
    filterState: { sort, byBakery, byHotDrinks },
  } = CartState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/products", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Acces-Control-Allow_Origin": "localhost:3000",
      },
      mode: "cors",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
        console.log('Aca me estoy trayendo el primer producto:', res.data[0]);
        setAllCategories([
          "All",
          ...new Set(res.data.map((item) => item.category)),
        ]);
        setLoading(true);

        return(()=> {
          setLoading(false)
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, [renderManager]);

  console.log('sort:', sort);
  console.log('byBakery:', byBakery);
  console.log('byHotDrinks:', byHotDrinks);
  if (sort) {
    sortedProducts = products.splice(0, 12);
    setProducts(sortedProducts);
  }

  if (byBakery) {
    sortedProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === byBakery
    );

    setProducts(sortedProducts);
  }

  if (byHotDrinks) {
    sortedProducts = products.filter(
      (item) => item.category === byHotDrinks
    )
    setProducts(sortedProducts);
  }

  

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <section className="container-xs bg-cream" style={{ padding: "0" }}>
          <div className="container-xs bg-cream pt-2 pb-5">
            <h3
              className="py-4 text-center brown-font font-poppins fw-bold"
              id="Handler"
            >
              Productos
            </h3>
            {/* mobile button */}
            <div className="text-center">
              <div class="dropdown pt-2 pb-4 d-md-none">
                <button
                  class="btn bg-brown white-font dropdown-toggle font-poppins"
                  type="button"
                  id="dropdownMenu2"
                  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                >
                  Todas las categorias
                </button>
                <ul
                  class="dropdown-menu bg-cream brown-font text-center ms-2 fw-bold"
                  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2"
                >
                  <ButtonAllProducts
                    buttons={allCategories}
                    className="fw-bold bg-brown-hover"
                  />
                  <ButtonBakery buttons={allCategories} />
                  <ButtonHotDrinks buttons={allCategories} />
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* mobile button ^ */}
            <div className="d-flex">
              <div
                className="d-none d-md-block ps-4 pe-5"
                style={{ width: "min-content" }}
              >
                <ButtonAllProducts buttons={allCategories} />
                <hr className="m-0" />
                <div className="filters">
                  <h5
                    className="brown-font mb-1 font-poppins fw-bold"
                    style={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }}
                  >
                    Pastelería
                  </h5>
                  <ul className="list-unstyled line-height-products mb-3">
                    <ButtonBakery buttons={allCategories} />
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h5
                    className="line-height-products mb-1 font-poppins fw-bold "
                    style={{ fontSize: "1.1rem" }}
                  >
                    Bebidas calientes
                  </h5>
                  <ul className="list-unstyled line-height-products">
                    <ButtonHotDrinks buttons={allCategories} />
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex flex-wrap posts pe-lg-4 pe-xl-5 w-100">
                <SingleProduct cards={products} />
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* <ButtonsPagination products={products} /> */}
          </div>
        </section>
      ) : (
        <div className="bg-cream">Loading...</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

**Buttons.jsx**
This is where the filter logic is, i don't think the problem is in this code beacause the console error says that it's in the Products.jsx file but you never know. Plus I think is important to understand the logic

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { CartState } from "../$-context/Context";
import "../css/Colors.css";


export const ButtonAllProducts = ({ buttons, filter }) => {
  console.log('buttons:', buttons);
  const {
    filterDispatch,
  } = CartState();
  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map((cat, i) => {
        if (cat === "All") {
          console.log('cat:', cat)
          return (
            <li
              key={i}
              className="brown-font line-height-products d-block mb-1 container-category font-poppins"
              style={{cursor: "pointer"}}
              onClick={() => filterDispatch({
                type: "SORT_ALL",
                payload: cat
              })}
            >
              Todos los productos
            </li>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export const ButtonHotDrinks = ({ buttons, filter }) => {
  const {
    filterDispatch,
  } = CartState();
  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map((cat, i) => {
        if (cat === "Café" || cat === "Té" || cat === "Chocolate") {
          return (
            <li
              key={i}
              onClick={() => filterDispatch({
                type: "FILTER_BY_HOT_DRINKS",
                payload: cat
              })}
              className="brown-font d-block container-category font-bitter"
            >
              {cat}
            </li>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export const ButtonBakery = ({ buttons, filter }) => {
  const {
    filterDispatch,
  } = CartState();
  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map((cat, i) => {
        if (
          cat !== "Café" &&
          cat !== "Té" &&
          cat !== "Chocolate" &&
          cat !== "All"
        ) {
          return (
            <li
              key={i}
              onClick={() => filterDispatch({
                type: "FILTER_BY_BAKERY",
                payload: cat
              })}
              className="brown-font d-block container-category font-bitter "
            >
              {cat}
            </li>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export const ButtonsPagination = ({products}) => {
  

  const cardsPerPage = 12;
  const allCategories = [
    "All",
    ...new Set(products.map((item) => item.category)),
  ];
 
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(products.splice(0, cardsPerPage));
  


  const totalCards = products.length;

  const nextHandler = () => {
    const nextPage = currentPage + 1;
    const firstNextIndex = nextPage * cardsPerPage;
    if (firstNextIndex === totalCards) return;

    setCards(products.splice(firstNextIndex, cardsPerPage));
    setCurrentPage(nextPage);
  };

  const prevHandler = () => {
    const prevPage = currentPage - 1;
    const firstPrevIndex = prevPage * cardsPerPage;
    if (firstPrevIndex < 0) return;

    setCards(products.splice(firstPrevIndex, cardsPerPage));
    setCurrentPage(prevPage);
  };



  return (
    <div className="text-center p-2">
      <div aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
          <li class="page-item">
            <a
              class="page-link bg-brown cream-font font-poppins rounded-3"
              href="#Handler"
              aria-label="Previous"
            >
              <span onClick={prevHandler} aria-hidden="true">
                Anterior
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-item">
            <a
              class="page-link bg-brown cream-font font-poppins rounded-3"
              href="#Handler"
              aria-label="Next"
            >
              <span onClick={nextHandler} aria-hidden="true">
                Siguiente
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And just in case there's a problem with the context here it is.

**Context.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from "react";
import { cartReducer, filterReducer } from "./Reducer";

const Cart = createContext();



const Context = ({ children }) => {
 
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, {
    cart: [],
  });

  
  const [filterState, filterDispatch] = useReducer(filterReducer, {
    sort: "",
    byBakery: "",
    byHotDrinks: ""
  });
  

  return <Cart.Provider value={{ state, dispatch, filterState, filterDispatch }}>{children}</Cart.Provider>;
};

export default Context;

export const CartState = () => {
  return useContext(Cart);
};
```

And the reducers, you can ignore the cartReducer.

**Reducer.js**

```
export const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART":
      return { ...state, cart: [...state.cart, { ...action.payload, qty: 1 }] };

    case "REMOVE_FROM_CART":
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.filter((i) => i.id !== action.payload.id),
      };
    case "CHANGE_CART_QTY":
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.filter((i) =>
          i.id === action.payload.id ? (i.qty = action.payload.qty) : i.qty
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


export const filterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SORT_ALL":
      console.log(state);
      return { ...state, sort: action.payload };
    case "FILTER_BY_BAKERY":
      console.log(state);
      return { ...state, byBakery: action.payload };
    case "FILTER_BY_HOT_DRINKS":
      console.log(state);
      return { ...state, byHotDrinks: action.payload };
  
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Finally if you wanna see the whole proyect here's the github repo
https://github.com/marcom25/panaderia-proyect.git

Comment: In your products.jsx-file you are updating hooks in your function, placed inside ifs. Each time you set a hook the application will rerender, and therefore causing and infinite loop. You should place the calls to setProducts ether inside an useEffect, or as a direct action when you fex press a button

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot, I'll get to that then